# I am trying to tell the program to display insufficient input. unless those 5 are selected

Tags: python-3.x

```
while True:
        if users_choice!= ('1','2','3','4','5'):
            print ('Insufficient input Method')
            break
```

This is inside my main loop. i dont want to place and if for each one.

Comment: Related: [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/451834109)

Answer (score 3):

Use `users_choice not in ('1','2','3','4','5')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    if users_choice not in ('1','2','3','4','5'):
        print ('Insufficient input Method')
        break
```

Operator `!=` is actually trying to compare a `string` with `tuple`. That's why `!=` wont work here.

To understand clearly, test this code

```
users_choice = '0'
while True:
    print(type(users_choice))
    print(type(('1','2','3','4','5')))

    if users_choice not in ('1','2','3','4','5'):
        print ('Insufficient input Method')
        break
```